# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device Docker, but I have space

Tags: python, docker

As the title suggests I'm running jupyter in a docker container and I'm getting the OSError from python deep in the scikit learn/numpy library at the following line:

```
pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
```

I've done some troubleshooting, and most of the problems people seem to have is their hard drive or RAM actually running out of space, which isn't the case for me AFAIK.

This is what my df looks like:

```
Filesystem                    1K-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           16419976          0    16419976   0% /dev
tmpfs                           3288208      26320     3261888   1% /run
/dev/sdb7                     125996884   72177548    47395992  61% /
tmpfs                          16441036     238972    16202064   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5120          4        5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          16441036          0    16441036   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2                         98304      32651       65653  34% /boot/efi
tmpfs                           3288208         68     3288140   1% /run/user/1000
//192.168.1.173/ppo-server3 16864389368 5382399064 11481990304  32% /mnt/ppo-server3
```

This is what my free looks like:

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       32882072     7808928    14265280      219224    10807864    24357276
Swap:        976892      684392      292500
```

Am I looking at the right df and free outputs? Both of them are being run from a bash instance inside the container.

Comment: Do you have, by any chance `quota` installed on the system? On some linux systems, you can restrict certain users...

Comment: hi, quota is not installed on the host (ubuntu) or docker.

Comment: Maybe something is going on in your code that is causing this to explode and cause this? Did you try running this code locally to see if you can replicate some kind of failure with the code?

Comment: Be sure to also check inode usage (`df -i`); running out of inodes can be the cause of this error if you're running with the `overlay` storage driver https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#limitations-on-overlayfs-compatibility

Comment: I've checked inodes, they seem to be fine. Also, running the exact same notebook not in docker does not yield this error.

Comment: I just bumped into the same problem as you when running sklearn in Jupyter in a Docker container. The problem turned out to be parallelization: I was trying to run 2 jobs at the same time and this somehow consumes a lot of space during pickle serialization. Sending a single job fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device` while installing scikit-learn during **docker build**, how to tackle it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in the coment by @PeerEZ , this happens when sklearn attempts to parallelize jobs.

sklearn attempts to communicate between processes by writing to /dev/shm, which is limited to 64mb on docker containers.

You can try running with n_jobs=1 as suggested by @PeerEZ (if you can't restart the container), or if parallellization is required, try running the container using the `--shm-size` option to set a bigger size for /dev/shm . Eg. -

```
docker run --shm-size=512m <image-name>
```

Answer (score 69):

Docker leaves dangling images around that can take up your space. To clean up after docker, run the following:

```
docker system prune -af
```

We can use the ‘until’ keyword with the ‘–filter’ option to remove objects that are created before a given timestamp or duration as shown below (objects older than 2 minutes):

```
docker system prune -a --filter “until=2m”
```

or in older versions of docker:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f 'status=exited')
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```

This will remove exited and dangling images, which hopefully clears out device space.

[More reading](https://www.educba.com/docker-system-prune/)

Meta: Putting this answer here because it's the top stack-overflow result for that failure and this is a possible fix for it.

Comment: Thank-you for the best answer for pruning, this resolved my issue.

Comment: docker system prune -af will delete everything

Comment: "docker system prune -af will delete everything."  No, it won't remove any containers that are actively running.

Comment: This is dangerous and bad advice.  it is highly unlikely that anybody with this issue would want to delete *every* image on their system that is not currently running.

Comment: Re: "dangerous and bad advice."
At least 50 people have given this a vote, so it feels safe enough. The point of containers is that you can recreate the ones you need to run. I also linked to the docs for other parameters you can pass into `prune`.

Comment: Alert! Please don't use this. It will remove all the images from your machine (Not useful for the issue specified).

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem when run parallel process in a Docker.
The trouble is that by default some precess use /dev/shm for storing some cache data and the size of that location in linux is by default about 64MB.
You can change de route where your parallel jobs store the cache with this two codelines in python. If the person that is reading this is using Pandarallel this solution can will help you.

```
import os

os.environ['JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER'] = '/tmp'
```

For users of pandarallel add this line too

```
pandarallel.initialize(use_memory_fs = False )
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, I received the same error and the problem was that one of my apps log files (`laravel.log`) was almost 11GB in size. Deleting that file resolved my problem.